# Trying to set label text, "Cannot call 'operator +' with arguments (const string, series[float])"

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

As the title suggests, I was creating a variable for a label's text I was attempting to set. I'm not super experienced but I personally don't see any mistakes, what's the issue? For whatever reason, I tried replacing '+' with 'and' but that didn't work, if that matters.

Here's the text:

```
labelText = 
     "8 Pair Strength by JustUncleL" + 
     "\n_____________" + "\n" +
     "\nAUD : " + AUD +
     "\nCAD : " + CAD + 
     "\nCHF : " + CHF + 
     "\nEUR : " + EUR + 
     "\nGBP : " + GBP + 
     "\nJPY : " + JPY + 
     "\nNZD : " + NZD + 
     "\nUSD : " + USD
```

I don't see why it shouldn't work, but maybe I was dumb and missed something.

Disclaimer: I am not JustUncleL.

EDIT:

So thanks to @e2e4 for the help. There are two things, however.

When using the replay mode, it plots a new label every bar, which obviously overlaps with each other. I have the 'no overlapping labels' checked on, if that matters.

After some playing around, this is the script for the creation of the label:

```
if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, low, text = labelText, style=label.style_label_down, color=#000000, size=size.normal, textcolor=color.white, yloc=yloc.abovebar)
```

Another, probably impossible question:

Is it possible to automatically order the values numerically, from highest to lowest? This isn't strictly required, so if you don't know, that is okay.

Comment: Please include in your question the values with which these variables are initialised (`AUD`, `CAD`, ....)

Comment: @trincot

`eur = tsi(EUR, eightprfast, eightprslow)

gbp = tsi(GBP, eightprfast, eightprslow)

jpy = tsi(JPY, eightprfast, eightprslow)

usd = tsi(USD, eightprfast, eightprslow)

aud = tsi(AUD, eightprfast, eightprslow)

cad = tsi(CAD, eightprfast, eightprslow)

chf = tsi(CHF, eightprfast, eightprslow)

nzd = tsi(NZD, eightprfast, eightprslow)`

Is this sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are `AUD`, `CAD` etc float variables ? You have to convert them to string with `tostring()` function:

```
// debug
AUD = 5
CAD = 5
CHF = 5
EUR = 5
GBP = 5
JPY = 5
NZD = 5
USD = 5

labelText = 
     "8 Pair Strength by JustUncleL" + 
     "\n_____________" + "\n" +
     "\nAUD : " + tostring(AUD) +
     "\nCAD : " + tostring(CAD) + 
     "\nCHF : " + tostring(CHF) + 
     "\nEUR : " + tostring(EUR) + 
     "\nGBP : " + tostring(GBP) + 
     "\nJPY : " + tostring(JPY) + 
     "\nNZD : " + tostring(NZD) + 
     "\nUSD : " + tostring(USD) 


if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, low, text = labelText, style=label.style_circle)
```

Comment: Apparently so, according to an error. I tried what you suggested and it appeared to have worked, but the label isn't appearing. 

I'm using this:

`horizontalOffset  = input(10, "Label Horizontal Offest")
verticalOffset = input(0, "Label Vertical Offset", minval = 0)`

`label.set_xy(_label, timenow + round(change(time)*horizontalOffset), ohlc4[verticalOffset])`

I also had to remove the `resolution` argument from the `study` function because it's incompatible with functions that 'have side effects'. It doesn't appear to have fucked up anything else.

Comment: Update your answer with a full code of the label drawing, you are missing some parts (ex: label assignment)